# reading HTTP response

Tags: c++, http

i'm creating a simple HTTP client to download a specific file from the web, i got a problem when i'm reading the data, here's my loop:

```
    do{
        client.readString(aux, 256);
        req.append(aux);
    }while(client.canRead());
```

client is a TCPClient object, this is fine, the method canRead use select() to test if there is available data, i think that the program read the data so fast that sometimes canRead is called before the new data income and return false, so i dont read all the response, to prove what i'm saying i use this code:

```
    AGAIN:
    do{
        client.readString(aux, 256);
        req.append(aux);
    }while((test = client.canRead()));

    if(!test){
        std::cout << "false\n";
        std::cout << req << std::endl << std::endl;
        system("pause>null");
        goto AGAIN;
    }
```

so when i go back to AGAIN, there is more data to be read, i know that the canRead method works fine, the problem is that i dont know when to stop reading the data, and depend of this method clearly not recommended. To solve this i see only two solutions, put some delays(Sleep) on the code or process the data directly from the socket file, but before i try it i came here to look for better solutions, is there an official way to do this? if can anyone help me i'll thank you.

Comment: You need to figure out from the http headers how much data you'll need to read. That's the only reliable way of doing this.

Comment: "i know that the canRead method works fine" - I bet it doesn't. from your description it sounds like its non-blocking, but then your app logic is incorrect.

Comment: You need to take `select` out of this loop altogether. Read the HTTP specification.

Comment: anyways, we need code we can reason about (and perhaps test..). voting to close.

Comment: What's this `TCPClient` object you are talking about?

Comment: the code dons't matter that much, consider that he runs right(if doesn't this is my problem later), right now i'm just looking for a good method to read for all the data efficiently, and the sockets are on block mode. TCPClient is a class that i created to handle C sockets functions

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, using a method to peek the data, i peek the data until i found a first '\r\n\r\n' that indicates the end of the response header, then i get the size until this '\r\n\r\n' and read this amount of data from the socket, so i process the header: see if there is a content-length or a transfer-encoding(right now i only suport chunked because is the only one that my program needs) member and call a scpecific method to "decode" the response body. So the code is:

```
    do{
        //if the header never ends....
        if(req.size() > MAX_HEADER_SIZE)
            throw std::runtime_error("Invalid HTTP header.");

        req = peekAvailable(client);
    }while((header_end = req.find("\r\n\r\n")) == std::string::npos);

    client.readString(req, header_end + 4);
    //... Here comes the part to interpret the header information...
```

And the peekAvailable method is:

```
    std::string peekAvailable(TCPClient& client){
    uint32 available_data;
    std::string data;

    while((available_data = client.getAvailableData()) == 0){
        //Here implement a timeout counter....
        Sleep(1);
    }

    client.peekString(data, available_data);

    return data;
    }
```

Thanks all for attention.